# Showing that cellular homology gives a chain complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I've just been introduced to the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms, and as an example, we are constructing cellular homology. Let $X$ be a CW complex and define $C_n(X)$ to be the free abelian group generated by $n$-cells of $X$. Define boundary homomorphisms $C_{n}(X)\to C_{n-1}(X)$ by, where $e_\alpha^n$ is an $n$-cell of $X$  and $e^{n-1}_\beta$ an $(n-1)$-cell
$$d_n[e^n_\alpha]=\sum_\beta c_{\alpha\beta} [e^{n-1}_\beta]$$
Define the coefficients $c_{\alpha\beta}$ to be the degree of the map
$$S^{n-1}\xrightarrow{\chi_\alpha} X_{n-1}\to X_{n-1}/(X_{n-1}\setminus e^{n-1}_\beta)\to S^{n-1}$$
Where $\chi_\alpha$ is the attaching map of $e^n_\alpha$, the second map collapses everything but $e^{n-1}_\beta$ to a point, and the last map is the characteristic map of $e^{n-1}_\beta$. My question is, how does this give a chain complex? I can't easily see that $d^2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough outline. You can find this explained precisely in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", Section 2.2.

Rather than defining $C_n(X)$ in the informal manner you describe, it is better to define it formally as the relative singular homology group
$$C_n(X) = H_n(X_n,X_{n-1})
$$
You can then *prove* that $C_n(X)$ is a free abelian group, with a basis element for each $n$ cell $e^n_\alpha$, where that basis element can be described explicitly as the image of the generator of $H_n(D^n,S^{n-1}) \approx \mathbb Z$ under the homomorphism induced by the characteristic map $x^n_\alpha : (D^n,S^{n-1}) \to (X_n,X_{n-1})$ of the cell $e^n_\alpha$. And then you can *prove* that the boundary homomorphism you describe is identical to a connecting homomorphism in the long exact sequence of the triple $(X_n,X_{n-1},X_{n-2})$, namely
$$H_n(X_n,X_{n-1}) \mapsto H_{n-1}(X_{n-1},X_{n-2})
$$
And, finally, you can do a diagram chase to *prove* that the composition of two successive boundary homomorphisms factors through the composition of two successive terms of an exact sequence, namely through
$$H_n(X^n) \mapsto H_n(X^n,X^{n-1}) \mapsto H_{n-1}(X^{n-1})
$$
I cannot quite reproduce the diagram here because [you can't draw diagonal arrows in mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14986/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-diagonal-arrow-in-a-commutative-diagram), but here's the best I can do:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H_n(X^n)  \\
@AAA \\
H_{n+1}(X^{n+1},X^{n}) @>>> H_n(X^n,X^{n-1}) @>>> H_{n-1}(X^{n-1},X^{n-2}) \\
@. @. @AAA \\
@. @. H_{n-1}(X^{n-1})
\end{CD}
The vertical arrows are homomorphisms of certain long exact sequences of pairs. If you draw in the two diagonal arrows of negative slope then you'll get two commutative triangles and a 3 term exact sequence of negative slope.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but we were introduced to homology with the axioms, and haven't done singular homology at all yet. I know this is a (very) nonstandard approach to this but I was wondering if there was another way to see this (the lecturer seemed to think it wasn't difficult). Thank you!

Comment: Well, I agree with the lecturer, because the singular homology arguments aren't difficult.

Comment: But, to warn other potential answerers, you should include in your question any hidden restrictions.

Comment: Guess it's time to look into singular homology then. Many thanks for the guidance.